# Can the permission to access user's profile picture be removed in Facebook login oauth?

Tags: permissions, facebook-login, hwioauthbundle

I can request for permissions specifying the scope like this:

```
        facebook:
            type: facebook
            client_id: ''
            client_secret: ''
            scope: "email, user_birthday"
```

and when logging in, I get asked for permissions for name, profile picture, email and birthday.

I would like to remove the permission for profile picture, since I don't need it in my app. From what I read, name and picture are default permissions, so does that mean they cannot be overridden?